# Timeseries and its visualisation

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a quarter of a million events lieke this:

```
                 Slot Anzahl Nutzung TimeSlotNr WochenSlots Tag
1 2011-01-01 00:00:00      2   Firma          1         242   1
2 2011-01-01 00:00:00     50  Privat          1         242   1
3 2011-01-01 00:30:00      1   Firma          2         243   1
4 2011-01-01 00:30:00     49  Privat          2         243   1
5 2011-01-01 01:00:00      1   Firma          3         244   1
6 2011-01-01 01:00:00     48  Privat          3         244   1
```

A slot represents half 30 minutes, "Anzahl" is the number of events in a slot, the first slot starts at 2011-01-01 00:00:00 "WochenSlots" is the TimeSlotNr %% 336 and starts on a saturday 00:00:00. So i want to see the distribution in a week.

[image: You see the development of bookings since 2011 by customertype. The peeks and holes are errors.]

[image: And the same data agregated to weeks (monday 00:00 - sunday 23:00)]

What I want to do now is:

- show the dates in x-scale (monday 00:00 - sunday 24:00)
- show lines (envelopes) which shows the distribution for x% of the events.

And i have no idea, how to do that.

```
  ggplot(data=PB2) + 
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = WochenSlots, y = Anzahl, colour = Nutzung), alpha=0.6) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    facet_wrap(~Nutzung,
               shrink = TRUE,
               nrow = 2,
               scales = "free_y")
```

> dput(PB2[1:100, ])
>   structure(list(Slot = structure(c(1293840000, 1293840000, 1293841800, 
>   1293841800, 1293843600, 1293843600, 1293845400, 1293845400, 1293847200, 
>   1293847200, 1293849000, 1293849000, 1293850800, 1293850800, 1293852600, 
>   1293852600, 1293854400, 1293854400, 1293856200, 1293856200, 1293858000, 
>   1293858000, 1293859800, 1293859800, 1293861600, 1293861600, 1293863400, 
>   1293863400, 1293865200, 1293865200, 1293867000, 1293867000, 1293868800, 
>   1293868800, 1293870600, 1293870600, 1293872400, 1293872400, 1293874200, 
>   1293874200, 1293876000, 1293876000, 1293877800, 1293877800, 1293879600, 
>   1293879600, 1293881400, 1293881400, 1293883200, 1293883200, 1293885000, 
>   1293885000, 1293886800, 1293886800, 1293888600, 1293888600, 1293890400, 
>   1293890400, 1293892200, 1293892200, 1293894000, 1293894000, 1293895800, 
>   1293895800, 1293897600, 1293897600, 1293899400, 1293899400, 1293901200, 
>   1293901200, 1293903000, 1293903000, 1293904800, 1293904800, 1293906600, 
>   1293906600, 1293908400, 1293908400, 1293910200, 1293910200, 1293912000, 
>   1293912000, 1293913800, 1293913800, 1293915600, 1293915600, 1293917400, 
>   1293917400, 1293919200, 1293919200, 1293921000, 1293921000, 1293922800, 
>   1293922800, 1293924600, 1293924600, 1293926400, 1293926400, 1293928200, 
>   1293928200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
>       Anzahl = c(2L, 50L, 1L, 49L, 1L, 48L, 1L, 43L, 1L, 43L, 1L, 
>       30L, 1L, 27L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 17L, 
>       0L, 17L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 17L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 19L, 2L, 19L, 2L, 
>       19L, 2L, 20L, 2L, 21L, 2L, 21L, 2L, 20L, 2L, 18L, 2L, 22L, 
>       2L, 24L, 3L, 25L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 30L, 1L, 33L, 1L, 32L, 1L, 
>       28L, 2L, 24L, 2L, 25L, 2L, 25L, 2L, 22L, 2L, 20L, 1L, 15L, 
>       2L, 14L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 
>       8L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L), Nutzung = c("Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", "Privat", "Firma", 
>       "Privat", "Firma", "Privat"), TimeSlotNr = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
>       2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
>       10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 
>       16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
>       22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
>       28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 
>       34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 
>       40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 
>       46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 50L), WochenSlots = c(242, 
>       242, 243, 243, 244, 244, 245, 245, 246, 246, 247, 247, 248, 
>       248, 249, 249, 250, 250, 251, 251, 252, 252, 253, 253, 254, 
>       254, 255, 255, 256, 256, 257, 257, 258, 258, 259, 259, 260, 
>       260, 261, 261, 262, 262, 263, 263, 264, 264, 265, 265, 266, 
>       266, 267, 267, 268, 268, 269, 269, 270, 270, 271, 271, 272, 
>       272, 273, 273, 274, 274, 275, 275, 276, 276, 277, 277, 278, 
>       278, 279, 279, 280, 280, 281, 281, 282, 282, 283, 283, 284, 
>       284, 285, 285, 286, 286, 287, 287, 288, 288, 289, 289, 290, 
>       290, 291, 291), Tag = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L)), .Names = c("Slot", "Anzahl", "Nutzung", "TimeSlotNr", 
>   "WochenSlots", "Tag"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: For the first bullet, ensure that `Slot` is of class `POSIXct` (`PB2$Slot = as.POSIXct(PB2$Slot)`) and then use `Slot` as the x mapping. For the second, do you mean you want a curve that shows, for each x-value, the y-value above which X% of the events occur?

Comment: For the second, do you mean you want a curve that shows, for each x-value, the y-value above which X% of the events occur? YES

Comment: Can you provide a data sample using `dput`? For example, paste into your question the output of `dput(PB2[1:100, ])` to provide the first 100 rows of data.

Comment: I provided a sample as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like quantile regression might be what you need. The data sample you posted only has one observation at each time point, so I've created some fake data for illustration. In the plot below, we use a flexible spline function for the regression function and we draw regression lines at the 25th and 75th percentiles of the data. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantreg)
library(splines)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
dat = data.frame(x=runif(1e4,0,20))
dat$y = cos(dat$x) + 10 + rnorm(1e4, 2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.1, colour="blue", size=0.5) +
  geom_quantile(formula=y ~ ns(x, 10), quantiles=c(0.25, 0.75),
                colour="red", size=1) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is it right to say, at the topspline the propability for an event is 75% or do i have to set the value in ns(x, 10) to 1 for that?

Comment: For this example 25% of the points have y-values that are above the top curve and 75% have y-values that are above the bottom curve. With your data, `Anzahl` is a count of events rather than the magnitude of a measurement, so I'm not sure how a line like this would be relevant. Can you could provide more context on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I share cars. And the minimum timeslot you can book a car, is half an hour. So i built a vector of time "Slot" from 2011-1-1 00:00 till today 2017-09-01 24:00 in 30-minutes-intervals and counted, which of the cars have been used in Slots between Slot[n] and Slot[n+1]. Furthermore I looked, if the booking was a residential "Privat" or a company "Firma" usage and made different counts for both..

Comment: Then i wanted to know the average usage in a wekk from monday till sunday and took the number of the timeslog %% 336 to put all count at the same time in a week together. There are many slots , 233758/2 slots with the counts ofe residential and 233758/2 with the counts of business usage, stored in Anzahl. First i want to have an idea for usage in the past and then i want to estimate the propability to have a residential user in mai 2018 on a monady, 12.00 °clock.

Comment: For that i will look to the first diagram and extrapolate a line in the futue and then i look to the second diagram an calculate the distribution in a week. I know, that si not realy true in a mathematical sense, but i think, it supports my needs.